# MPMoviePlayerController repeat mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I have used MPMovieController for video play. I need to repeat the video for user define times. So how can i check the repeat count for the specific video if i have enabled the repeatMode.

Comment: Can i just repeat the video for defined number of times

Comment: post ur code ? you use custom slider ?

Comment: you have to do this logically there is no delegate method for repeating certain number you have to use int value and if condition for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think by using "MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification" this notification function you  can check count..i.e repeat mode , repeats while it's going to finish playing...& playing is finishing u can get this notification...so you can maintain your count.